# Can We Use CSS for Images Which are Only Wider than A Fixed Size?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, image, image-processing

I want to add a style of images of my blog, However, if i simply use CSS then the style will get applied to all the images. The problem is small images (<500px wide) will look bad with this style.

Is there any method available (maybe conditional CSS) for archiving what i want.

Comment: Not with CSS alone, no. You cannot check that kind of information. However, if you can use JavaScript, then you'd be able to assign classes to images that are larger or smaller than some size.

Comment: Can you share a sample code with your issue here. There might be a way to do this but must see example to check if the scenario allows a solution that is pure html/css.

Answer (score 2):

Afaik there's no pure CSS way to do this but it's quite easy with JavaScript (and jQuery):

```
$("img").each(function() {
  if ($(this).width() > 500)
    $(this).addClass("large-img");
});
```

Then

```
.large-img {
  /* special styles here */
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to applying CSS styles to a subset of elements, the most commonly adopted approach is to make use of [CSS Classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Class_selectors). These enable you to indicate to the browser that you wish to apply a specific style to certain elements.

```
img.my-style {
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```

```
<html>
  <body>
    <img src="/images/small.png">
    <img class="my-style" src="/images/large.png">
  </body>
</html>
```

This, of course, requires that you be able to edit the HTML of your website, which may not always be the case. In situations where you are unable to modify the HTML, you may be able to use other CSS selectors to identify the elements you wish to apply your style to.

For example, if your large images only appear within a certain portion of your website, then you could apply your style to images within that portion:

```
#content>img {
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```

```
<html>
  <body>
    <img src="/images/small.png">
    <div id="content">
      <img src="/images/large.png">
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

It may also be possible for you to use the `width=""` attribute's value to select images, however this is likely to be cumbersome and fragile, so I would advise avoiding it if possible.

```
img[width=700] {
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```

```
<html>
  <body>
    <img src="/images/small.png" width="150">
    <img src="/images/large.png" width="700">
  </body>
</html>
```

Unfortunately, to the best of my knowledge it is not possible for CSS rules to take into account the dynamic size of an image element, so you will need to select the option above which best suits your use case. I have ordered them with the "best" option (in my opinion) first and the worst option (in my opinion) last.